# how to define padding of a container in responsive design

Tags: css

I have styles like:

```
.main-title {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font: normal 1.5em "League Gothic", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Now I don't know that exact height of `main-title` container as it is `multi-line` title.

How may I declare consistent padding irrespective of it's height?

Comment: Could you elaborate what the issue is? Can't you just say `padding: Xpx`?

Comment: Using padding as a percent bases it off of the width and height of the element itself. So you could do `padding: 5%;` and on a 100px x 200px element, the padding would be 5px on the sides, and 10px on the top and bottom.

Comment: @Torr3nt: No, percentage padding is *always* based on the width, never the height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the normal padding rule will add consistent padding **irrespective** to the elements height.

```
.main-title {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can use percents, as Torr3nt mentioned, and that will make the padding **respective** to the **width** of the element's parent. I have created <kbd>[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/SMLjy/2/)</kbd> to show what I mean by this. If the element is positioned absolute than the percent will be based of the closest relatively positioned ancestor.

Comment: A percentage padding is always relative to the element's width, even on the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but after doing some testing, i have found that the padding is relative to the element's parent width, check out the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's relative to its containing block. You can read about it in the [box model specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).